# No AirPlay in XBMC on EeePC (Debian)

Tags: debian, networking, settings, xbmc

I have a Asus EeePC (900 model I think) and I've installed Debian 6.0 on it. I've managed to get WiFi working on it and I've installed XBMC. It's working with our NAS drive on the network but for some reason, if I go to Settings->Network in XBMC, the only things that appear are General, SMB, and Internet Access. The main things I want/need are AirPlay and Remote Control - both of which I can not see settings anywhere.

I have installed ssh, and avahi-daemon also. Can anybody suggest why these options aren't available and how I can resolve the problem.

Thanks